# PHP code is returning "x=NAN"

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$a = $_GET["valA"];
$b = $_GET["valB"];
$c = $_GET["valC"];

$d = pow($b,2) - 4 * $a * $c;
$e = sqrt($d);
$f = $e - $b;
$g = 2 * $a;
$h = $f / $g;

echo "x = $h";
```

And it is returning:

```
x = NAN
```

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: Have you checked your values of `$_GET["valA"] $_GET["valB"] $_GET["valC"]` to make sure they are, in fact, numbers?

Comment: Something in your `$_GET` variables doesn't have the value you think it has. Post the HTML as well, please.

Comment: If `$_GET["valA"]` is zero, then yeah. Anyways you need to provide `$a`, $`b` and `$c`.

Comment: what is your url's query string ?

Comment: sometimes your $a / $b / $c are undefined or 0. thats why makes your $h is NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `$e = sqrt($d);`

Whenever `$d` gives a NEGATIVE value `sqrt($d)` returns NAN.

EXAMPLE

```
echo $e = sqrt(-4);  
          returns NAN
```

AND

```
echo $e = sqrt(4);
          returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**NAN** simply means **Not A Number**. The values you are pulling from the URL may be strings, which would cause this issue.

Also I think the problem may occur if you are taking the square root of a negative number.

You could use something like this to solve it

```
<?php
$a = 10;
$b = 20;
$c = 30;

$d = pow($b,2) - 4 * $a * $c;

if($d < 0){
        $d *= -1;
    }
$e = sqrt($d);
$f = $e - $b;
$g = 2 * $a;
$h = $f / $g;
?>
```

Comment: Seems to be comment more. Actually you have enough reputation to comment too

Comment: @Uchiha Sry.. I read only the question.